# How do I unlock 4G bands?

Tags: 4g, xiaomi-mi4

I'm using Xiaomi MI4. In India it doesnt support 4G bands, is there a way to unlock 4G bands for this device?

Comment: In general, 4G/LTE bands are locked by the manufacturer and cannot be altered.

Comment: Is it possible after rooting the phone..

Comment: No, rooting has nothing to do with the bands the device can access. http://www.howtogeek.com/135663/htg-explains-whats-the-difference-between-jailbreaking-rooting-and-unlocking/

Comment: @acejavelin Unless you have a mediatek processor, then you can use engineering mode to enable and disable bands

Comment: @DanBrown True... but the Xiaomi MI4 is a Snapdragon based device.

Comment: @acejavelin yeah, shame. Does it have a MTK-style mode?

Answer (score 1):

There has been an unlock method available for most Snapdragon 800/801 devices, and some forums claim it works for the MI 4 too. However, 1) it involves flashing a custom ROM *and* using a dangerous diagnostic tool, and 2) it doesn't unlock what the phone is not supposed to support (e.g. CDMA), nor is it guaranteed to unlock the band you want.

If you're still curious, take a look [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/sony/thread-progress-please-leave-im-updating-t2871269).

And before you leave, you should know that MI 4 has 3G and 4G variants. If you have the 3G variant then just give up - there's no hardware.

Comment: Thanks bud! I read the post on that link.. the one who had done it has already lost 2 phones. I think I'll restrain myself from going further with this.